# How to merge user options with default options using jQuery's extend() when options have a property array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to merge user option with default options using jQUery's `extend()` method when the options object has a property that has a value that is an array of objects

example:

```
    var settings4 = $.extend({
      type: 'one-panel', // 'one-panel' | 'two-panel'
      sidebarTargets: [
        {
          targetKey: 'sidebar-one',
          initialLoadPanelKey: 'panel1',
          emptyPanelMessage: '',
          sidebarWrapSelectorId: 'sidebar-container',
          sidebarPanelWrapTemplate: '<div class="sidebar-panel {panelInitialSlideCss}" id="{panelSelectorId}" data-panel-key="{panelKey}"></div>',
          showHeader: true,
          headerTemplate: '<div class="sidebar-header" id="sidebar-header">Header text</div>',
        },
        // if sidebarSettings.type == one-panel, this is not required
        {
          targetKey: 'sidebar-two',
          initialLoadPanelKey: 'none',
          emptyPanelMessage: '<span>No Notebooks Notes Found',
          sidebarWrapSelectorId: 'sidebar-container',
          sidebarPanelWrapTemplate: '<div class="sidebar-panel" id="{panelSelectorId}" data-panel-key="{panelKey}"></div>',
          showHeader: true,
          headerTemplate: '<div class="sidebar-header" id="sidebar-header">Header text</div>',
        },
        {
          targetKey: 'right-content-panel',
          selectorId: 'sidebar-container',
          cssClassLIst: 'content-panel content',
          showLoader: true, // when AJAX content is loaded, show a loader spinner
          loaderTemplate: '',
          initialInnerContent: '',
        },
        {
          targetKey: 'right-content-iframe-panel',
          selectorId: 'sidebar-container',
          cssClassLIst: 'content-panel content',
          iframeNameAttribute: 'content',
          template: '<iframe id="content-frame" src="default.html" name="content" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
        }  
      ],
    }, sidebarOptions);
```

---

The object property above `sidebarTargets` is the one in question.  It can contain any number of objects in the array.  How do I use jQuery's extend to merge options and handle a property like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't really do this using [`jQuery's extend` function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

The `extend` will be able to *extend* **objects** you have, if you send [`true` in your first argument](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN). The problem is that you have `Array`s in your object, and the `extend` will not know what to do with those Arrays.

If you are able to change the code to objects, this will work great:

```js
var a = {
  a: ['a'],
  b: {
    'c': 1
  }
}
var b = {
  a: ['b'],
  b: {
    'd': 2
  }
}
$.extend(a, b)
console.log('regular extend:')
console.log(a);
console.log('')

var a = {
  a: ['a'],
  b: {
    'c': 1
  }
}
var b = {
  a: ['b'],
  b: {
    'd': 2
  }
}
$.extend(true, a, b)
console.log('deep copy extend:')
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```